# How do I flag an inappropriate edit?

Tags: support, flagging, editing

I'd like to bring an edit to the attention of the moderators.  How do I do that?

I know how to flag a question, an answer and a comment, but not an edit.

(I don't want to get into an edit war.)

Comment: Raise a custom flag and explain in the reason box.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Thanks!  I suppose "custom flag" means choosing the last item in the list, that allows typing in a text input box.  But what am I flagging?  The answer that got edited?

Comment: Just explain whatever you think the problem is.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I take it the think I will flag is whatever post got edited.  I hope I got that right, and thank you.  ---  Would you like to make an Answer, by the way?

Comment: Another wacked by the "cooling off" period, I do not believe for one second you were verbally aggressive,negative  or rude to any person. So the only reason I can think of were the recent posts of yours which probably created a negative vibe in at least one MSE mod. If they think their suspensions are for the greater good by helping help Meta to survive, they are sorely mistaken. If anything their solution to suspend users who are *not* violent, rude or abusive has successfully created an air of tension, fear, and negativity among Meta users.

Comment: You have my support. No need to reply because I am sure suspended users' comments are tracked, even across different sites. Me? Paranoid? Noooooo what makes you say that? :) Peace.